# Binding commands in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a WPF project which implements the MVVM design pattern.

This is my xaml code in the Home.xaml file:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <myProject:ImageButton Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding MyPath}" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}">                                
    </myProject:ImageButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class MyClassDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public string MyPath { get; set; }

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return new NavigateToViewCommand(Container.Container.GetA<IMyViewModel>()); }
    }
}
```

I also have a file HomeViewModel which looks like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase, ILandingViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        items = new List<MyClassDto>
        {
            new MyClassDto
            {
                Name = "John",
                Path = "1.png"
            },
            new MyClassDto
            {
                Name = "Jack",
                Path = "2.png"
            }
        };

    }

    public IList<MyClassDto> items { get; set; }
}
```

**Where do I need to put the MyCommand method?**

At the moment, I see this in my Debug->Output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MyClassDto' (HashCode=25729862)'.
```

BindingExpression:Path=MyCommand; DataItem='MyClassDto' (HashCode=25729862); target element is 'ImageButton' (Name=''); target property
is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: As it stands now in `MyClassDto` class and not method but `ICommand`, or anything that implements `ICommand`, property

Comment: MVVM purists would say that you should put a property of type `CommandViewModel` into your ViewModel class `MyClassDto` and use a converter in the `Binding` which converts `CommandViewModel` to `ICommand`. This is because you should not use WPF specific data types (like `ICommand`) in the ViewModel, at least not from a purist's point of view.

Comment: @dkozl It doesn't work. Pls see the question again, I updated the MyClassDto class.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work you mean it still gives you binding expression error or just command is not triggered?

Comment: @dkozl Command is not triggered. The warning in the Output window isn't shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a MyCommand property of type ICommand in your MyClassDto class

Comment: It doesn't work. Pls see the question again, I updated the MyClassDto class.

Answer (score 0):

Is this sentence working?

```
new MyClassDto
{
    LanguageName = "Jack",
    Path = "2.png"
}
```

Probably you have anothe MyClassDto class somewhere with LanguageName and Path without MyCommand.

Comment: My point is your class does not have property LanguageName but you say this assignment is working so I doubt there is another class with the same name.